# tkinter in python not working and no web fix works

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to python and I am having a problem with tkinter that no one seems to explain. I am using the

```
from tinker import *
```

and when I run the program it errors out on the

```
window = tk()
```

i have tried to install tkinter but it tells me there is a new version of pip and tells me to run  `python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip` in the cmd prompt. this does nothing as it errors out in

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'i:\\python\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-22.3.1.dist-info\\entry_points.txt'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

what am I doing wrong? please help

I have tried everything that all the web sites have explained to no avail. and a simple

```
from tkinter import * 
window = tk()
```

still errors out. :(

no window pops up

Comment: Are you calling `window.mainloop()` to start the app? What error are you seeing? Please include any relevant traceback(s) in the body of your question.

Comment: Saying that your program "errors out" is very vague, and does not help us solve the problem.  If you're getting an error, **show it to us**.

Comment: your first line should be `window = Tk()` with a capital `T`. Case is important in Python. Additionally, `tkinter` is part of the Python standard library - you get it when you install Python.

Comment: @MattDMo good catch! I didn't even notice that!

Comment: In addition to the mistake with `window = tk()` as pointed out in another comment, you've also misspelled `tkinter` as `tinker` in the import statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works as expected - I've fixed a few things based on the information you've given and the comments from other users.

```
import tkinter as tk  # star imports are best avoided

# notice the 'tk.' namespace prefix here - this is the way to go!
window = tk.Tk()  # instantiate Tk
label = tk.Label(window, text='Hello, World!')  # add a widget
label.pack()  # add the widget to the window
window.mainloop()  # start the app
```

Barring that, try running this command:

```
python.exe -m tkinter
```

It should bring up a basic example tkinter app. If that works, you'll know that tkinter is at least installed correctly on your machine.